# Где искать плагины для PHP в частности для Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, веб-программирование, laravel, framework

Если я ошибаюсь исправьте меня но мне кажется что  экосистема вокруг Javascript более структурирована и понятна нежели чем у PHP .

Например Для Javascript выбор плагинов это  npmjs.com
а для PHP (в частности Laravel) не понятна  какой ресурс выбрать, для поиска или сравнения плагинов.

Прощу помочь мне разобраться в экосистеме PHP и Laravel

Answer (score 2):

В PHP используется [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

Основной репозиторий пакетов: https://packagist.org/

Для Laravel: https://packalyst.com/